# Are there power levels mentioned in Dragon Ball Super Broly?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, japanese-language, dragon-ball-movies

In Dragon Ball Super Broly there are some scenes where characters are scanning other warriors for power levels with scouters. But since the movie is only in japanese for now, it's hard to know if there are power levels mentioned in the movie. Are there power levels mentioned in Dragon Ball Super Broly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. *Paragus* is said to have a power level of **4200**. Also, when Paragus scans Broly on Planet Vampa when he's a child, he has a power level of **920**.